# Insert hierarchical data into table with specific condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have the following table

```
CREATE TABLE Topic_details(
   topicid BIGINT  NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1)
  ,parent_topicid BIGINT  
  ,description NVARCHAR(184) NOT NULL
  ,code   NVARCHAR(43) NOT NULL
  ,lang_id INT 
  ,entryby INT  NOT NULL
  ,enrtydate DATE  NOT NULL
  ,last_updateby INT 
  ,last_update_date DATE 
);
```

Now insert some sample data into it

```
INSERT INTO Topic_details(topicid,parent_topicid,description,code,lang_id,entryby,enrtydate,last_updateby,last_update_date)
VALUES
 (1,NULL,N'Overview of C',N'Overview of C',NULL,10238,'2017-06-10 13:09:52.297',NULL,NULL)
,(2,1,N'Features of C',N'Features of C',NULL,10238,'2017-06-10 13:10:09.060',NULL,NULL)
,(3,1,N'C Language Applications',N'C Language Applications',NULL,10238,'2017-06-10 13:13:13.607',NULL,NULL)
,(4,1,N'C Program Execution',N'C Program Execution',NULL,10238,'2017-06-10 13:13:32.623',NULL,NULL)
,(5,1,N'What is Interpreter ?',N'What is Interpreter ?',NULL,10238,'2017-06-10 13:14:17.897',NULL,NULL)
```

Now in my application there is a requirement to insert these kind of data from excel.

**Now the sheet that user will be uploaded consists three columns**

```
ParentTopicName|TopicName|Code|
---------------|---------|----|
```

**and let have some sample data into it,**

```
 ParentTopicName|TopicName|Code|
 ---------------|---------|----|
                |Joins    |Join|
----------------|---------|----|    
      Joins     | Inner J | IJ |
-------------------------------|
      Joins     | Left J  | LJ |
```

Now I have a datatable which will store excel's data.

Now, In procedure

```
Create ROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_upload_topic_subtopic]
@entry_by bigint = null,
@lang_id nvarchar(20) = null,
@dtTopicSubtopic ttTopicSubtopic  ReadOnly -- to store value from datatable
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO dbo.topic_details([description], code,entryby,enrtydate,lang_id)
    SELECT d.TopicName, d.TopicCode,@entry_by,Getdate(),1 from @dtTopicSubtopic as d

    UPDATE td
    SET td.parent_topicid= ptd.topicid
    FROM dbo.topic_details td
    INNER JOIN @dtTopicSubtopic d ON d.TopicName=td.[description]
    INNER JOIN topic_details ptd ON d.ParentTopic=ptd.[description]
END
```

**This will store data as expected in Topic_Details table
After storing into table,**

```
 ---------------------------------------------------
                      Topic_Details
 ---------------------------------------------------
 TopicId   |ParentTopiID|desciption|Code|.....
 ---------------|------------|----------|----|.....
        1       | NULL       | Joins    |Join|.....
 ---------------|------------|----------|----|.....
        2       |   1        | Inner J  | IJ |.....
 ---------------|------------|----------|----|.....
        3       |    inserted data..................
  --------------|------------------------------------ 
        4       |    inserted data...................
  --------------|-------------------------------------
```

Now later suppose I am inserting another row from excel. (**please note *Inner j* is already present in my table and I'm inserting *Inner J* again.**)

```
 ParentTopicName|TopicName |Code|
 ---------------|--------- |----|
                |Inner J   |Ij  |
----------------|--------- |----|  
    Inner J     |Some Thing| dj |
```

**This will insert data into Topic_details table as follows**

```
 TopicId   |ParentTopiID|desciption|Code|.....
 ---------------|------------|----------|----|.....
        1       | NULL       | Joins    |Join|.....
 ---------------|------------|----------|----|.....
        2       |   1        | Inner J  | IJ |.....
        3...... 
        4......
        5      |    Null     |   Inner J  | IJ | .... 
  -------------|-------------|------------|----|-----
        6      |   2         |   Something|hfdj|......
```

But as 'Inner J' is already present in my table so,

1. TopicId with 5 will not be inserted. **(solved)**

2. As 'Something' is the child of 'Inner J' so parentid of 'Something' will be 2 because 'Inner J' is already present in my table.

Final Out Put what I want

```
------------------------------------------------------                   
                   Topic_details
-------------------------------------------------------
 TopicId        |ParentTopiID|desciption|Code|.....
 ---------------|------------|----------|----|.....
        1       | NULL       | Joins    |Join|.....
 ---------------|------------|----------|----|.....
        2       |   1        | Inner J  | IJ |.....
 ---------------|------------|----------|-----|       
        3.....................
        4.....................
        5.....................    
  -------------|-------------|------------|----|-----
       6       |   2         |   Something|hfdj|......
```

How can I achieve this ?

Comment: How this question is related with c# language?

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. It seems you need some help with something. It even seems like it is sql server inserting data you need help with. The problem is that you have not provided much of anything in the way of details. Here is a great place to start making this question better. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: @SeanLange Thanks for your guidance, hope I am able to draw a clear view now :)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you do not want to insert duplicate records.

```
INSERT INTO dbo.topic_details([description], code,entryby,enrtydate,lang_id)
SELECT d.TopicName, d.TopicCode,@entry_by,Getdate(),1 from @dtTopicSubtopic as d
WHERE NOT EXISTS( SELECT * FROM dbo.topic_details AS Cur WHERE Cur.TopicName = d.TopicName AND Cur.TopicCode = d.TopicCode )
```

The above code checks if the record with a given `TopicName` and `TopicCode` already exists in `dbo.topic_details` and does not insert it.

### Update:

After much confusion, which as it turns out, is due to the fact that OP query already works.

One other Issue I notice is that `topicid BIGINT` and `parent_topicid INTEGER` are of different data types. They should use the same as these columns establish a relation and will be frequently joined.

Comment: Thanks for your reply :) , yes I do want to remove duplicate row while uploading as well as previous matching record's Id (TopicId) will be parentTopicid of uploaded child element.Please refer last part of my thread.

Comment: My code prevents duplicates rows from being inserted. I don't understand what other problems you are having.

Comment: I have edited my question , please have a look sir :)

Comment: Much appreciated, but I have already mentioned that my table valued parameter i.e '@dtTopicSubtopic as d' does not have any column parent_topicid. See, a user will only know about Topic and its code right?  Is there any other way to get desired output @Alex sir?